# Is Mono installed in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, programming, mono

I am learning to program in Visual Basic .NET at school, and am using Visual Studio Express.

My teacher said that I can download Mono to practise programming at home, and as my exam is soon, I want to start practising.

I have read that it comes installed by default in some versions of Ubuntu. I'm currently using 13.04. I don't think it is installed already though.

What do I need to do to get mono? Would a sudo apt-get install mono-runtime do the job? Is there anything else I would need to do?

Thanks

Comment: Just got this error: Error while trying to load the project '/home/file/location/HelloWorld.vbproj': Project does not support framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just checked my installation of 13.04, and Mono is not installed.

To install Mono, this will install Mono Run-time, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-runtime
```

If mono Develop is what you're after, then

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

Mono focuses on compilers and run-time libraries and does not directly provide an IDE. MonoDevelop is a cross platform IDE mostly aimed at Mono/.NET developers. For more info see [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/), and [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Comment: Than you! So does the runtime let me run mono applications, and develop lets me make them?

Comment: if you're interested in development then you should consider using the `mono-complete` package

Answer (score 3):

It's easiest to install using the Ubuntu Software Center. Just search for "mono" in Ubuntu Software Center and you can install it from there. It's called "MonoDevelop". You can also use this link:
http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/monodevelop

Comment: Thanks! Do I need the Compiler add on for VB.NET as well?

Comment: If you're looking to compile Visual Basic .NET solutions, (as you said you are) then yeah, you will.