# I want to use Ubuntu for developing my application - pl help

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development

I am an Mfg Engg Professional with 30 years experience in CNC / CAD / CAM fields. I have stumbled upon an application for time & motion study and using VB.net SQL 2005 Express developed it into a full fledged app - with visual studio.

I am hearing the word that Ubuntu is a good system. Pl tell me if I can use it as a development plat form for my app development - to make it as a true open source one - preferably using the same .net, vb etc technologies.

I am a developer with VB due to its easy visibility of books plus training courses for the same. I am not very much conversant with 'open source' though I feel it is a good thing..

Can some one help me with some suggestions? Will it help me 'stay afloat' with some kind of revenue flow - even though my app will become an open source ? If so, how?

Pl reply.

Rgds

Renga Iyengar
Chennai
India

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please be a little bit more specific or detailed about whay you're trying to accomplish, or take a look at [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 2):

The [mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/VisualBasic.NET_support) is a project for developing .NET applications on non-Microsoft operating systems. They appear to have visual basic support, but are better know for C#. I recommend looking into mono software.

Just because you develop applications on Linux doesn't mean your code has to be open-source, just as if you develop on Windows you can make your code open source. For more information on making (or getting involved in) open source projects, take a look at https://github.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can still develop .net application in linux using **[Mono framework](http://www.mono-project.com/)** which is a similar opensource implementation of MS .net Framework with additions, however you won't be using your usual IDE (visual studio) but there is a very decent replacement IDE named **[Mono Develop](http://monodevelop.com/)** it supports many languages including VB.net. This is for 1st part, concerning SQL 2005 please refer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336114/how-to-connect-ubuntu-to-a-ms-sql-server-2005) maybe you'll need to install sqlserver in another machine and access it from Ubuntu.
To install Mono framework use

```
sudo apt-get install mono-runtime
```

To install monodevelop

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

More information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295249/is-mono-installed-in-13-04)